# Is there any fantasy or fiction layout with magic and a Modern Age, Contemporanean Age or further developed society?

Tags: magic, magical-theory, society

Exactly as the title says.

We are very used to fiction or fantasy with a magic system where the plot develops within a Medieval Age society. However it's very difficult (I haven't found any yet, other than Star Wars) to find a Modern Age, Contemporanean Age or further developed society with a magic system.

Could you point out which fantasy or fiction series would the first published under the mentioned category?

**Note:**

-The world of Naruto is mostly medieval in terms of social status, wars, mode of cultivation, etc. Sure, they have magically produced electricity, and contemporanean hospitals, but they lack the modern military advancements. Maybe the country of the winter has contemporanean things such as guns and trains, but their social development is still on the medieval era, and none of the countries has begun full exploration of the globe.

Comment: If you are looking for a book/tv series recommendation this question is off-topic unfortunately. You could phrase the question to look for the *first* fantasy or science fiction series that satisfies your criteria, that would certainly be on-topic

Comment: "Urban Fantasy" or "Contemporary Fantasy" are both search terms that might be useful to you here, although there's also secondary-world fantasy with post-industrial-revolution societies (like The Goblin Emperor) and "SF-fantasy" set in the far future with space travel and also magic (like Starship's Mage or Coldfire).

Comment: China Mieville's *Perdido Street Station*, *The Scar*, and *Iron Council*.

Comment: R. F. Kuang's *The Poppy War*, *The Dragon Republic*, and *The Burning God*.

Comment: Yoon Ha Lee's *Machinery of Empire*.

Comment: Marvel Comics' *The New Mutants*, *Dr. Strange*, etc., etc.

Comment: Kat Howard's _An Unkindness of Magicians_ is an example of Urban Fantasy.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is a whole subset of the Fantasy genre, called [Contemporary Fantasy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contemporary_fantasy) and there are multiple examples in mainstream media such as:

### Western media

- Harry Potter (ok, it does have a quasi-medieval magic world coexisting with the modern world, so not the best example)
- Buffy the Vampire Slayer and Angel
- Charmed
- Percy Jackson
- The Mortal Instruments (aka Shadowhunters)
- Supernatural
- The Dresden Files
- American Gods and Good Omens
- RPG: White Wolf's World of Darkness
- RPG: Shadowrun

### Eastern media (mainly anime / manga)

- Yu Yu Hakusho (a personal favorite)
- A Certain Magical Index and spinoffs
- Most of Type-Moon's works (Tsukihime, Fate series)
- Hellsing
- Final Fantasy VII and VIII

Comment: There are also a bunch of novels set in the Shadowrun universe.